# Like fan page when accepting app permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-page

Can I add a permission when accepting my app to ask to the user to share their public_profile and like a fan page at the same time?
Or I need to use the like button after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's impossible. But you can add a like action to your application if it is a native IOS or Android, desctop application. And after your action is approved you can ask permission for publsihing actions. And publish that action on your server side.